# Analyzing vlookup

Tags: excel, data-analysis, analysis

I have certain month (August 2022) and available ID of users who were present in this date. In one extract (file1) it has 99149 rows, however month ago extract (file2) shown 9800

I do vlookup both ways - so looking for ID's -> lookup value is ID from file1, lookup array is ID from file2 and I can find 1251 N/A, the other way I can find 202 ID.

Does it indicate something? Does it proves something? I'm kind of lost with understanding what goes on. Its probably wrong ETL or even deeper - extracts, but I have to make sure

Answer (score 0):

Without more context, you can use two helper columns to identify missing elements from one column into another and vice versa as follow:

[image: sample excel file]

In column `D2`:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A6,B2:B5,1,0)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

In column `E2`:

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2:B5,A2:A6,1,0)), TRUE, FALSE)
```

so in **File1** there are three IDs: `6,8,10` that are not in **File2** and in **File2** there are two items: `1,3` not in **File1**.